# How do I time the user input from a Scanner in Java, and place that input into a category based on certain time intervals?

Tags: java

I want the user to answer a question, but their input is timed from the prompt to when they press enter. Then based on how long they took, I want that question and answer pair to be stored somewhere.

Question1: What is the powerhouse of the cell?
Answer: Mitochondria
The answer is *correct*, and user took *6 seconds* to press enter

Store Question1 into deck A (because all t<10 seconds should be in deck A)

Question2:What is inflammation in the cardiac muscle called?
Answer: Myocarditis
The answer is *correct*, and user took *15 seconds* to press enter

Store Question2 into deck C. (because all t >=15 seconds but less than 20 should be in deck C)

I can program everything around this problem, I just can't seem to be able to time and store the user input based on that time. Any assistance would be great, thanks!

Comment: Take the current time (t1) right _before_ you ask for user input via the `Scanner`, then call for user input and right after that take the current time (t2) again. Finally, do `t2 - t1` and convert to seconds if needed to get the duration.

Answer (score 2):

I think you simply can save the time before and after you read the user input. I created a small example for one of your questions:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
        
        System.out.println("What is the powerhouse of the cell?"); // First question

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); // Save start time
        String answer = scanner.nextLine();  // Read user input
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); // Save time after enter
        long questionTime = (endTime - startTime) / 1000; // Calculate difference and convert to seconds

        if (answer.equals("Mitochondria")) { // Check if answer is correct and print output
            System.out.println("The answer is correct, and user took " + questionTime + " seconds to press enter");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The answer is wrong, and user took " + questionTime + " seconds to press enter");
        }
    }
}
```

Console log:

```
What is the powerhouse of the cell?
Mitochondria
The answer is correct, and user took 3 seconds to press enter
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Right before asking, capture the current time using `Instant.now()`;
2. Right after they press *enter*, capture the then current time using `Instant.now()`;
3. Use `Duration::between` to get the duration between those two instants.
4. Format the `Duration` to the desired format, e.g.

   ```java
   String.format("%ss and %sms", d.getSeconds(), d.toMillisPart())
   ```